# HTML within IFrame not allowing DOM interaction

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have some old code that is using iFrames.  The code displays fine on the screen, however, when I try to manipulate some of the elements via javascript it can't find them.

For example it says Table is NULL (however, I'm looking at it on the screen).

How can I manipulate the HTML when it resides in an iFrame?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this javascript code:

```
alert(window.frames['iframe_layer1'].document.forms['pagectrls'].elements['ptObj_listbox2'].innerHTML);
```

I got the following error from FireBug:
**window.frames.iframe_layer1.document.forms.pagectrls.elements.ptObj_listbox2 is undefined**

Here is a output of code from the iFrame:

```
<div id="popcont_1" class="popupContainer" style="width: 740px; height: 520px; left: 507px; top: 0px; display: block; z-index: 97;">
<iframe id="iframe_layer1" style="width: 738px; display: block;" class="popupFrame" name="iframe_layer1" onload="top.iframeOnload();" src="default.asp?bn=0.7346613&amp;wpo=1&amp;p=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
<html>
```

```
<div class="TabPanel" id="paneltab3" name="paneltab3" style="display: inline;"> <div class="colvis">55</div><div style="border: 1px solid rgb(136, 141, 119); position: absolute; width: 198px; z-index: 90; left: 147px; top: 8px; overflow: hidden;" id="ptObj_listbox1main"><div style="z-index: 95; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 198px; height: 112px; position: relative;" id="ptObj_listbox1div"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 199px;" id="ptObj_listbox1"><tbody><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row0" lstindx="0" class="LUGridRowHighlight"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Personnel Management</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row1" lstindx="1" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Safety Management</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row2" lstindx="2" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">COBRA Administration</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row3" lstindx="3" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Training Course</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row4" lstindx="4" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Training Administration</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row5" lstindx="5" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Job Profile</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row6" lstindx="6" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Position Control</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row7" lstindx="7" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Requisition Tracking</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row8" lstindx="8" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Applicant Management</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row9" lstindx="9" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Management</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,1, &quot;&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row10" lstindx="10" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Survey</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none;" id="ptObj_listbox1archetype"><tbody><tr onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox1&quot;, &quot;&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=1" id="ptObj_listbox1Row" lstindx="0" class="LUGridRow"><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><!-- Listbox End -->

<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(136, 141, 119); position: absolute; width: 198px; z-index: 90; left: 147px; top: 127px; overflow: hidden;" id="ptObj_listbox2main"><div style="z-index: 95; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 198px; height: 240px; position: relative;" id="ptObj_listbox2div"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 0px; width: 199px;" id="ptObj_listbox2"><tbody><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row0" lstindx="0" class="LUGridRowHighlight"><td ptcheck="true" style="width: 19px;" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Personal</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-1</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row1" lstindx="1" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Status</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-2</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row2" lstindx="2" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Compensation</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-3</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row3" lstindx="3" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Position History</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-4</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row4" lstindx="4" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Performance Appraisals</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-5</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row5" lstindx="5" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Benefits</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-6</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row6" lstindx="6" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Background</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-7</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row7" lstindx="7" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Medical/Wellness</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-8</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row8" lstindx="8" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Training/Competency</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-9</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row9" lstindx="9" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Attendance</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-10</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row10" lstindx="10" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Timesheet Information</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-11</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row11" lstindx="11" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">Payroll Information</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-12</a></td></tr><tr ondblclick="lbRowDblClick(this,2, &quot;0&quot;);" onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row12" lstindx="12" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="true" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckTrue"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">User Fields</a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)">EMP-13</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none;" id="ptObj_listbox2archetype"><tbody><tr onclick="lbRowClick(this,&quot;ptObj_listbox2&quot;, &quot;0&quot;);" pturl="ajxcmd.asp?datactrl=&amp;xCmd=LSTRCLICK&amp;xLstNDX=2" id="ptObj_listbox2Row" lstindx="0" class="LUGridRow"><td ptcheck="false" style="width: 19px;" class="LUGridCell"><div class="lbCheckFalse"></div></td><td class="LUGridCell"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td><td class="ColVis"><a class="dummyLinks" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><!-- Listbox End -->

<input type="button" onclick="btnClick(this, 'ListRowUp');" style="top: 127px; left: 360px; width: 60px; height: 24px;" value="Up" tabindex="-1" id="ptObj_bbutton1" class="ptbutton" pttype="b" ptlayndx="61" ptdisp="false" ptpopup=""><div class="colvis">62</div><input type="button" onclick="btnClick(this, 'ListRowDown');" style="top: 153px; left: 360px; width: 60px; height: 24px;" value="Down" tabindex="-1" id="ptObj_bbutton2" class="ptbutton" pttype="b" ptlayndx="62" ptdisp="false" ptpopup=""><div class="colvis">63</div></div>


</body></html>
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: does the iframe source belong to a different domain?

Comment: You should be able to if you are working from the parent frame. Any chance you can post more detail for us to see?

Comment: What detail would you need to see?  The source does not belong to another domain.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/).

Comment: What does your code look like? Knowing only what you want to do isn't going to help us know why what you are actually doing is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to get your iframe and content in following manner

```
var iframe_layer1 = document.getElementById('iframe_layer1');

iframe_layer1.contentWindow.document.forms['pagectrls'] ... // and so on
```

also if you know the id of element then you can use it to find the element without using form here you can access your table as

vat myTable = iframe_layer1.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ptObj_listbox2');
alert(myTable .innerHTML);

Answer (score 3):

All modern browsers allow you to debug code AND interactivaly execute JavaScript. This is useful in cases like your - stop when exception is thrown and start decreasing your statement till it works.

Most likely in your case there is some element missing (i.e. I don't see FORM tag in your sample HTML).

Try to debug and execute statements interactivly till you find which one fails:

```
window.frames['iframe_layer1']
window.frames['iframe_layer1'].document
window.frames['iframe_layer1'].document.forms['pagectrls']
window.frames['iframe_layer1'].document.forms['pagectrls'].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent window, and `IFRAME` content are being delivered from different domains, you won't be able to use javascript to manipulate the DOM content loaded from the other domain. It's a security feature of modern browsers called the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: I don't think that is it.  As it is coming from the same domain.  Thanks though.